# MySQL Python unsure of the error

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I have a question. When I execute the whole thing, it throws me an error stating: TypeError: not enough arguments for format string. I guess it has to do with the error in the cur.execute("INSERT INTO `modules`(module_name, no_of_scripts, gsm, exam_type, exam_date, school) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")  but unsure what could be causing the issue.Help please thanks!

Below is a reference code:

```
 db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
                         user="schooluser",
                         passwd="",
                         db="exam_import")
    cur = db.cursor()
    csv_data = csv.reader(file('Modules.csv'))
    for row in csv_data:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO `modules`(module_name, no_of_scripts, gsm, exam_type, exam_date, school) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM modules")
    for row in cur.fetchall():

            self.name = row[0]
            self.sheetsperpaper = row[1]
            self.paperweightlol = row[2]
            self.exam_type1 = row[3]
            self.exam_series1 = row[4]
            self.exam_school1 = row[5]

            self.module_name.append(self.name)
            self.sheets.append(self.sheetsperpaper)
            self.paperweight.append(self.paperweightlol)
            self.exam_type.append(self.exam_type1)
            self.exam_series.append(self.exam_series1)
            self.exam_school.append(self.exam_school1)

    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

Comment: You are not giving any value to the values of  ' cur.execute("INSERT INTO `modules`(module_name, no_of_scripts, gsm, exam_type, exam_date, school) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")'

Comment: Yes, but the values I am taking is from a CSV file, the %s is meant to take the values in the CSV file.

Comment: But you don´t asign them anywhere

Comment: What is inside `Modules.csv`?

Comment: Inside Modules.csv has values that is seperated by commas. This is the tables of the database that I followed to insert the values into the CSV file:
CREATE TABLE exam_import (module_name VARCHAR(500), no_of_scripts INT(10), gsm INT(3), exam_type VARCHAR(6), exam_date VARCHAR(100), school VARCHAR (5));

Comment: @nacho so how do i go about resolving the issue?

Comment: It is because as I tried running it on my Raspberry Pi for a project and it was running well with no issues However after a few minutes this error popped out, which I had tried changing the syntax but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to asign values to your query

```
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO `modules`(module_name, no_of_scripts, gsm, exam_type, exam_date, school) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)" % (row[0],int(row[1]),int(row[2]),row[3],row[4],row[5]))
```

so you asign the values of each column of the row to your query (if the order is not that, you can change the row[x] position)

Comment: I did just exactly that, it throws me an ProgrammingError:(1064,"you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near <my csv values>.

Comment: so does it mean the row[0],... i change it to my Database variables?

Comment: I suposed that all data where strings, can you give the DB CREATE statement and the first lines of your csv?

Comment: DB create statement:
CREATE TABLE exam_import (module_name VARCHAR(500), no_of_scripts INT(10), gsm INT(3), exam_type VARCHAR(6), exam_date VARCHAR(100), school VARCHAR (5));

Comment: First lines of my csv (seperated with a comma, without headers):
E114 English Language,24,70,ESE,Sep-17,SOI

Comment: @Nelson I have changed the answer so it should work now. You had two integer columns, so you must use %d instead of %s

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error once. I found this thing somewhere that when inserting a char or varchar value into the database in python code use single quotes around`'%s'`.
I guess this should work for you too.

```
"insert into table_name(column_name) values('%s')" % value
```